# MS Query Excel to Access reserved word, misspelling or punctuation error

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I am new to SQL and I am trying to link my excel workbook (2010) to an Access database table (2010) using MS Query to return some summary statistics on our Fleet. I have a parameter for the month which is located in a cell in the excel workbook.

The code I have is below and I get the error message

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that
>   is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

I have used the parameter for more simple information and it works perfectly, however, this code seems to be missing something.

```
SELECT tbl_FLEET_HISTORY.`Type`, 
Sum(tbl_FLEET_HISTORY.`Number Railcars`) AS `QTY_Wagons`
Sum(tbl_FLEET_HISTORY.`Number of Platforms: loading units`) AS `QTY_Platforms`
Sum(tbl_FLEET_HISTORY.`Days Leased in Month`) AS `Days_Leased`
Sum(tbl_FLEET_HISTORY.`Days Available`) AS `Days_Available`
Sum(tbl_FLEET_HISTORY.`Daily Rate`) AS `Daily_Rate`
FROM tbl_FLEET_HISTORY tbl_FLEET_HISTORY
WHERE (tbl_FLEET_HISTORY.`Month`=?)
and (tbl_FLEET_HISTORY.`Leased During Month`=`Yes`)
GROUP BY tbl_FLEET_HISTORY.`Type`
```

I have run through a lot of the answers to this topic but I have not been able to resolve the issue.

I would really appreciate any assistance. If there is any additional information needed please let me know.

Comment: Start by using square brackets instead of backticks to delimit your fied names. In access, field names are escaped using square brackets.

Comment: And use double quotes for string constants.

Comment: Thanks Gentlemen. I have tried this query and now I get the following error, [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error 9missing operator0 in query expression 'fh.Month = Pa_RaM000 AND fh.Leased During Month = [Yes]' . is this linked to the fact that I have a parameter in the excel workbook?

Comment: I've got it sorted now. I went to the Access database and solved the query there with the help of your comments and copied that into the MS Query in excel. I removed the parameter and will look into refining that part at another time. I was getting a type mis-match error so it was quicker just to add the value I needed. Thanks very much for you assistance!

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, the query would look more like:

```
SELECT fh.Type, 
       SUM(fh.[Number Railcars]) AS QTY_Wagons,
       SUM(fh.[Number of Platforms: loading units]) AS QTY_Platforms,
       SUM(fh.[Days Leased in Month]) AS Days_Leased,
       SUM(fh.[Days Available]) AS Days_Available,
       SUM(fh.[Daily Rate]) AS Daily_Rate
FROM tbl_FLEET_HISTORY as fh
WHERE fh.Month = ? AND
      fh.Leased During Month = "Yes"
GROUP BY fh.type;
```

Notes:

- String constants are delimited by double quotes in MS Access.
- Backticks are not used at all.  Column names are escaped using square braces.
- You do not need to escape the aliases you are assigning.
- You need commas between the expressions in the `SELECT`.